# jasper report exclude summary page from PAGE NUMBER

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a jasper report with number of groups and a summary page.I need to exclude that summary page from page number.For example if I have 10 pages (including summary) then I need show the page number on my footer as **1 of 9**,**2 of 9** etc.But currently it shows **1 of 10**,**2 of 10**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that this is a somewhat ugly workaround and works only if your summary consists of fixed amount of pages.

When you design your report, and put in `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` that shows you the amount of pages - you can actually call some Java logic before the output is shown. Specifically you can just subtract 1 and get the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can just subtract 1 and get the result you need.
For Example:
[CDATA[new java.lang.Integer($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()-1)]]